# Accessing Window Files in Linux

Tags: partitioning, windows, mount

After mounting the windows partition is the command prompt (sudo mount  -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /media/c) I can't see the document files. The folders shown are Boot, Dell, preload, recovery, sources, system volume info. The other executable files are Autorun/inf, bootmgr, Desktop.ini, Info.exe, Master.log and a bunch of protect.dutch etc. How do you view the files?

Comment: Could it be you mounted the recovery partition and not the partition windows is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you've chosen the wrong partition. This looks like a generic recovery partition that OEMs stick on new PCs to save them bundling installation CDs.

Use something like Disk Utility, GParted or `sudo fdisk -l | grep '^/dev/sd'` to figure out what the real partition number is, then unmount whatever you have on `/media/c` now and then try mounting the new choice. You're probably looking for the biggest ntfs partition.

Comment: I might be wrong but I would expect windows to be on `1` (so sda1 or sdb1).